# MATLAB: Plot inside a For Loop

Tags: matlab

Pardon my ignorance here, but I cannot seem to understand how to plot data inside a simple MATLAB for loop. I currently have the following:

```
sigma=[.9 .9250 .95 .95];
gamma=[1 .0784 .54 .4862];
F=[0 0 .25 0;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0];
for e=0:.01:.2
   R_0=max(eig(F*inv((eye(4)-[sigma(1)*(1-gamma(1)) 0 0 0;...
       sigma(1)*gamma(1) sigma(2)*(1-gamma(2)) 0 0;...
       0 sigma(2)*gamma(2) sigma(3)*(1-gamma(3))*(1-e) sigma(4)*gamma(4);...
       0 0 sigma(3)*gamma(3)*(1-e) sigma(4)*(1-gamma(4))]))))
end
```

I am trying to plot R_0 with respect to e. The for loop works in that for each value of e (0, then .01, then .02, up until 2), the code gives me values for R_0 (1.1049, then 1.0138, then .9365, up until .3949). So basically I have a group of points that I am trying to plot and then connect with a line, but I cannot seem to figure out how to plot this.

Once again, this question seems extremely simple, but I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to collect the `R_0` values in each iteratiion (in the current version of your code, you are overwritting the value at each iteration).

To save all the value, you have to use `R_0` an array and introduce a counter to be incremented in the loop; then you can use the `plot` function to plot the data.

In the following code you can see:

the initialization of the conter `cnt`

its increment at each itaration

the use of the `plot` function after the loop

```
sigma=[.9 .9250 .95 .95];
gamma=[1 .0784 .54 .4862];
F=[0 0 .25 0;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0];

% Initialize the counter
cnt=0;

for e=0:.01:.2
   % Increment the counter
   cnt=cnt+1;
   % Use R_0 as an array and store the value of each iteration

   R_0(cnt)=max(eig(F*inv((eye(4)-[sigma(1)*(1-gamma(1)) 0 0 0;...
      sigma(1)*gamma(1) sigma(2)*(1-gamma(2)) 0 0;...
      0 sigma(2)*gamma(2) sigma(3)*(1-gamma(3))*(1-e) sigma(4)*gamma(4);...
      0 0 sigma(3)*gamma(3)*(1-e) sigma(4)*(1-gamma(4))]))))
end
% Plot the results
plot([0:.01:.2],R_0,'o-')
```

[image]

Hope this helps,

Qapla'

Comment: Thanks. Just as a follow up questions, if I were to add a line to the graph at y=1 (as is shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO7sc.jpg) what would be the best way to find this intersection

Comment: Sorry, I keep pressing enter;
    graph1=plot([0:.01:.2],R_0)
    hold on
    graph2=plot(xlim,[1 1])

Comment: I'm not sure this will be the best way, but you can use `polyfit` to find the coefficients of a polynomial fitting the `R_0` data, then use `roots` to get the roots of the polynomial. To find the intersection of a specific `y` value, you have to subtract the target `y` value (in your case `1`) when evaluating the coefficients of the polynomial. One you've got the roots, you use `imag` to downselect only the real roots.